# cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex) Give Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, android, media, mediastore, database-cursor

I am trying to load all the images present in an Android devices using the Media Store.

This is what I am doing

```
public void getImages(Context context) {
    File Image_File;
    final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED ;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,
        null, orderBy);

    if (cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        final int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Image_File = new File(cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

But the below line gives me an error

```
Image_File = new File(cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
```

This is the error which is appearing

> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
>       Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference

And this is the full Stack Trace

> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
>           at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
>           at java.io.File.(File.java:134)
>           at PackageName.getImages(ClassName.java:87)
>           at PackageName.ClassName$load.doInBackground(ClassName.java:52)
>           at PackageName.ClassName$load.doInBackground(ClassName.java:39)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

**I am aware that there are other SO posts which talk about this topic such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177616/cursor-getstring-null-pointer-exception-on-version-6-0) but then I feel they are nowhere related to my case.**

This crash happens in Android versions from 5.0 to 7.0(My app's minimum Android version is 5.0).

Any Help would be grateful as I am not able to retrace the issue on my Phone.

Comment: It's not `cursor.getString()` but passing a null to `File` constructor.

Comment: Thanks @laalto . But Is it possible for cursor.getString() to return a Null File?

Comment: It can return null strings if there's no data in that column.

Comment: @laalto OK. Should I first declare a String variable then assign the value of `cursor.getString()` to that variable and then check if that variable is null or not? And if it is not null then only I should declare a File Variable with that path. Will that be fine?

Comment: Likely yes. The code you posted is not doing anything useful with the data yet, so it's hard to say what would be enough but not too much.

Comment: @laalto Thanks. But can you clarify that what do you exactly mean by `data`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your cursor is already past the previous entry with cursor.moveToNext() call since you have already called cursor.moveToFirst().

```
moveToNext()

/**
     * Move the cursor to the next row.
     *
     * <p>This method will return false if the cursor is already past the
     * last entry in the result set.
     *
     * @return whether the move succeeded.
     */
```

Did you try:

```
try{
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Image_File = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)));
        }
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }finally {
       if (cursor != null) {
           cursor.close();
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Can you please frameup a code and put it in the answer on how you would suggest me to retrieve all the Images.

Comment: Thanks. But I think that this code will only catch the error and close the cursor, But then what will happen to the loading of the Images?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"; 

 Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,
                orderBy);

// Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        for(int i =0;i<cursor.getCount();i++){
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);//List of all record
            image_file =new File(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
        }

        cursor.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you please explain how would this prevent the error, As if the value `cursor.getString(columnIndex)` is null it will again crash the app.

Comment: Now you will get the last item from this it will not throw null have you tried.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this code before using the code which is being used by me right now. But even this code use to give Null Pointer.